# Cuando hago click en una notificación de FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) se reinicia la aplicación

Tags: android, firebase, push, notification

Cada vez que recibo una notificación enviada a través de la consola de FCM y la pulso, en vez de iniciar la aplicación en el estado que se encuentra en background, me lanza mi activity Main, que en este caso es un login. He implementado mi clase service y así la he llamado en el Manifest de mi aplicación:

```xml
<service
     android:name=".utils.FirebasePushNotificationsService"
     android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Después en mi clase FirebasePushNotificationsService tan solo he sobreescrito el método onMessageReceived, para cuando estoy en primer plano, lance un Toast:

```kotlin
class FirebasePushNotificationsService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            Toast.makeText(
                baseContext,
                remoteMessage.notification?.body,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Y en el archivo Manifest tengo mis activities tal que así:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".views.DashboardActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing" />

<activity
    android:name=".views.SmartphoneActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

<activity
    android:name=".views.CustomActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

<activity
    android:name=".views.LoginActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

El primer activity que inicia es el LoginActivity y después navega hacia el DashboardActivity, y si estando en este activity, pongo la app en segundo plano, cuando recibo la notificación y la pulso, me manda al LoginActivity de nuevo... He probado a poner los launchMode, pero no me ha funcionado o no he sabido implementarlos...

Comment: Lo importante es revisar el LogCat, de otra forma es algo complicado conocer la causa del problema.

Comment: @Jorgesys lo tengo revisado, es más, tengo puesto lineas de código para pintar en el log en cada parte donde pueda hacer una navegación al LoginActivity, pero según veo en ningún momento pasa por ahí... es como que cuando pulso la notificación, me manda ahí...

Comment: OK no pasa por ahí pero al cerrarse puedes ver algún mensaje en el LogCat?